# Cannot query a collection with dashes in its name though Solr JDBC

Tags: solr

We're having trouble querying a collection whose name contains dashes with Solr JDBC.

For example:

```
SELECT id FROM collection-with-dashes
```

Returns the following error message (I'm replacing the collection name with [collection] and the server URL with [server]):

```
SQL Error: java.sql.SQLException: java.io.IOException: --> http://[server]:8983/solr/[collection]_shard1_replica1/:Failed to execute sqlQuery 'select * from [collection] limit 200' against JDBC connection 'jdbc:calcitesolr:'.
Error while executing SQL "select * from [collection] limit 200": parse failed: Encountered "-" at line 1, column 21.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "ORDER" ...
    "LIMIT" ...
    "OFFSET" ...
    "FETCH" ...
    "NATURAL" ...
    "JOIN" ...
    "INNER" ...
    "LEFT" ...
    "RIGHT" ...
    "FULL" ...
    "CROSS" ...
    "," ...
    "OUTER" ...
    "EXTEND" ...
    "(" ...
    "." ...
    "AS" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    "TABLESAMPLE" ...
    "WHERE" ...
    "GROUP" ...
    "HAVING" ...
    "WINDOW" ...
    "UNION" ...
    "INTERSECT" ...
    "EXCEPT" ...
    "MINUS" ...
```

We've tried writing the collection name between square brackets, single quotes and double quotes, but neither works.

Comment: `BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` might map to `\``. Try to use `\`collection-name\``.

Answer (score 0):

Thenks, MatsLindh.
That worked properly.

Using back quotes it worked:

```
SELECT id FROM `collection-with-dashes`
```